# API display array map in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops

im having problem displaying this 2 loops in map. im using this map for the display but cant seem to display both of the loop.

Can i display them inside one loop only? like loop inside loop? Need help here tia

```
Choices Data

{testQuestionData.map(({choices}) => (
   <div>{choices.map((tchoices)=>
      <div>
         {tchoices.testChoices}
      </div>
        )}
   </div>
))} 

Question Data

{testQuestionData.map(td=>(
  <div className="col-md-12">
     {td.question.testQuestion}
         <label>Choices: {td.choicesDisplay}</label>
   </div>
))}

{
  "question": {
    "testQuestion": "Earth is flat?",
  },
  "choices": [
    {
      "testChoices": "true",
      "
    }
   {
      "testChoices": "false",
      "
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you mention the error you got?

Comment: i have no error, need some help can i make a one loop with that json? using map

Answer (score 0):

You have badly formatted data. You have a random `"` after the test choices and no `,` between the choices.

Your data should look like this

```
{
    "question": {
      "testQuestion": "Earth is flat?",
    },
    "choices": [
      {
        "testChoices": "true",        
      },
     {
        "testChoices": "false",        
      }
    ]
  }
```